# Some problems with the startDiscovery function in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

In this code, I would like to scan for non-register reachable bluetooth devices. 
The problem : when I use the "startDiscovery" on my BluetoothAdapter, the app just freezes.

Here is the code and thanks in advance for your help:

public class ClientActivity extends Activity {

```
private Set<BluetoothDevice> devices;
private BluetoothAdapter blueAdapt;
private BroadcastReceiver bluetoothReceiver;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_client);

    blueAdapt=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    devices = blueAdapt.getBondedDevices();

    for (BluetoothDevice blueDevice : devices)
        Toast.makeText(this, "Device = " + blueDevice.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    bluetoothReceiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Toast.makeText(ClientActivity.this, "FOUND", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    registerReceiver(bluetoothReceiver, filter);

    if (blueAdapt.isDiscovering()) blueAdapt.cancelDiscovery();
    blueAdapt.startDiscovery(); // Here is the problem
}

protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    blueAdapt.cancelDiscovery();
    unregisterReceiver(bluetoothReceiver);
}
```

}

Edit : here is the logcat obtained with the code above

```
01-29 13:01:18.397: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(16629): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
01-29 13:01:18.397: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(16629): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
01-29 13:01:18.397: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(16629): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
01-29 13:01:39.377: E/SpannableStringBuilder(16629): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
01-29 13:01:39.377: E/SpannableStringBuilder(16629): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
01-29 13:01:43.261: W/dalvikvm(16629): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417232a0)
01-29 13:01:43.261: E/AndroidRuntime(16629): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-950
01-29 13:01:43.261: E/AndroidRuntime(16629): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
01-29 13:01:43.261: E/AndroidRuntime(16629):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
01-29 13:01:43.261: E/AndroidRuntime(16629):    at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:361)
01-29 13:01:43.261: E/AndroidRuntime(16629):    at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:97)
01-29 13:01:43.261: E/AndroidRuntime(16629):    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:254)
01-29 13:01:43.261: E/AndroidRuntime(16629):    at com.example.momala.ClientActivity.run(ClientActivity.java:39)
01-29 13:01:43.261: E/AndroidRuntime(16629):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-29 13:01:50.448: I/Choreographer(16629): Skipped 427 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-29 13:01:50.768: V/MediaPlayer(16629): stop
01-29 13:01:50.768: D/AndroidRuntime(16629): Shutting down VM
01-29 13:01:50.768: W/dalvikvm(16629): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417232a0)
01-29 13:01:50.768: I/Process(16629): Sending signal. PID: 16629 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Had you try to put a breakpoint on Toast code row into onReceive method? I avoid to use Toast in a context different from the UI thread..

Comment: It would help to show us the output from LogCat

Comment: Edit of the first message to add the logcat